# converge absolutely/conditionally : (cos(npi)) / ((n+1)ln(n+1))?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is probably an extremely basic question, but I just cant figure it out. I have the series (cos(npi)) / ((n+1)ln(n+1)) from 1 to infinity. and this is atleast conditionally convergent I can see by the alternating test, since cos(npi) change between 1 and -1 only. but how do I conclude whether its absolutely or conditionally convergent? (which test do you think I should use to show it diverge for absolute sign for instance?), thanks in advance for tips/solutions!

Comment: Try using the Integral test for the series of absolute values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}$ diverges, you can use the integral test. So you have to calculate
$$
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+1)\ln(x+1)} \, dx
$$
This can be done by substitution. Can you see how?

Comment: hmm not exactly.. I didnt really think about the integral test since it seemed really hard to integrate

Comment: Try $u=\ln(x+1)$.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, could use the Cauchy condensation test: the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\ln n}$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty2^n\frac1{(2^n\log(2^n)}$ converges. The latter series simplifies to $\frac1{\log2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1n=\infty$.